# Lower bound for shortest problem

Tags: algorithms

Suppose given a weighted directed graph $G=(V,E)$.
We want, for each $v\in V$ find a path $P$ from other vertices to $v$ such that weight of $P$ is minimzed.

I can solve this by running Johnson's algorithm on $G$ and doing a linear traverse of matrix to find out for each $v$ minimum weight shortest path from other to $v$ in $O(n^3)$. But my problem is are there any lower bound that show us we can't do better in $\Omega(n^3)$?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple path: You cannot solve this in $O(n^3)$ time (unless $P=NP$).

If you allow the path to be non-simple: No.  Read about [all-pairs shortest paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#All-pairs_shortest_paths).

Comment: According to exercise 24.1.5 from CLRS book we can solve it by Bellma- Ford algorithm.

Comment: Now can we conclude that, we can solve it in $O(n^3)$ or not?